# Can a javascript closure function be altered by a user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

we have a code that makes some stuff:

```
$(function(){

  //websocket connection
  //ajax requests
  //other stuff

});
```

if the code was loaded the browser has compiled it, so can the user change this code and reload the page with the altered code?

because function that are inside this anonymous jquery function can't be executed in the browser console, thus they are not accessable, the question is: are there any posibilities to hack this type of code?

Comment: A user could just copy the anonymous function, including the code inside, to his console, and run it.

Comment: Using Chrome's DevTools, a user *can* indeed alter the function and recompile the whole script. But with other browsers they can still alter values and so on.

Comment: A person can run what ever he wants from the browser console. Not just your above code. :)

Comment: @Cerbrus But it would lose its scope...

Comment: It's client sided. That being said, you should always treat code that you execute on the client-side as unsafe and untrusted. Always check what data you receive at the server side; never trust client-side data, users can almost always alter it!

Comment: @MaxArt: Nothing a somewhat experienced developer can't handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user could just copy the anonymous function, including the code inside, to his console, and run it.
Basically, **any and all code** you send to the client can be accessed, modified, and run.

Validate anything that needs to be validated, server-side. Use client-side validation only to make your application "prettier".

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily copy to console in Google Chrome for example, changed and fired from there. And user can easily see this script for example in Sources tab. So yes, it's possible.
So if it's function that user cannot see I reccomend not to use Javascript or any script language on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your issue in particular, but a couple of recommendations.

- Never trust the user, nor anything that comes from the client. It can be easily manipulated. **ALWAYS** check the data server side. Check that the fields are the correct type, especially in languages like PHP, never use the entire POST data, always filter it.
- **Minify your code** and use **closure** this way you reduce the change the user can mess with your code
- Give access to user only to the parts that are his responsibility, this way if he messes with your code only he is damaged.
- Use secure cookies and https if you can. Check CSRF and XSS, and use ways to be safe of this.

You can't avoid that the user will do as he pleases, but you can make so he can only touch his data